# Combining 3 lists to create a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out the best way to take the following 3 lists:

```
name_list = ["potatoes", "milk", "butter"]
quant_list = [500, 200, 40]
unit_list = ["g", "ml", "g"]
```

and convert them to a list of dictionaries, in the following format:

```
target_list = [{"name": "potatoes", "quant_units": {"amount": 500, "unit": "g"}}, {"name": "milk", "quant_units": {"amount": 200, "unit": "ml"}}, {"name": "butter", "quant_units": {"amount": 40, "unit": "g"}}]
```

I'm really struggling to figure out the methods, loops required to do this.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what code *have* you written? You should have been able to make a start.

Comment: It's better that you start trying first and show where do you get stuck. Hint can you do *zip* and *dict comprehension* somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use list comprehension, which would make it a one-liner and generally is a really cool concept in python

```
name_list = ["potatoes", "milk", "butter"]
quant_list = [500, 200, 40]
unit_list = ["g", "ml", "g"]

[{'name': f'{food}', 'quant_units': {'amount': amount, 'unit': unit}}
for food, amount, unit in zip(name_list, quant_list, unit_list)]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'potatoes', 'quant_units': {'amount': 500, 'unit': 'g'}},
 {'name': 'milk', 'quant_units': {'amount': 200, 'unit': 'ml'}},
 {'name': 'butter', 'quant_units': {'amount': 40, 'unit': 'g'}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

```
res = []
for (a, b, c) in  zip(name_list, quant_list, unit_list):
    res.append({'name': a, 'quant_units': {'amount':b, 'unit':c}})
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'potatoes', 'quant_units': {'amount': 500, 'unit': 'g'}}, {'name': 'milk', 'quant_units': {'amount': 200, 'unit': 'ml'}}, {'name': 'butter', 'quant_units': {'amount': 40, 'unit': 'g'}}]
```

Comment: no reason to call `list` on `zip`, just iterate over the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
name_list = ["potatoes", "milk", "butter"]
quant_list = [500, 200, 40]
unit_list = ["g", "ml", "g"]
ans = []
for i,j,k in zip(name_list, quant_list, quant_list):
    ans.append({'name':i,'quant':j,'unit':k})
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'potatoes', 'quant': 500, 'unit': 500}, {'name': 'milk', 'quant': 200, 'unit': 200}, {'name': 'butter', 'quant': 40, 'unit': 40}]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```py
name_list = ["potatoes", "milk", "butter"]
quant_list = [500, 200, 40]
unit_list = ["g", "ml", "g"]

lst = []

for n, q, u in zip(name_list, quant_list, unit_list):
    lst.append({'name': n, 'quant_units': {'amount': q, 'unit': u}})

print(lst)
```

Output:

```py
[{'name': 'potatoes', 'quant_units': {'amount': 500, 'unit': 'g'}}, {'name': 'milk', 'quant_units': {'amount': 200, 'unit': 'ml'}}, {'name': 'butter', 'quant_units': {'amount': 40, 'unit': 'g'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this as an alternative solution if you have an equal number of list items:

```
list_dict = []
for i in range(len(name_list)):
    list_dict.append({'name':name_list[i], 'qaunt_list':{'amount':quant_list[i], 'unit':unit_list[i]}})
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'potatoes', 'qaunt_list': {'amount': 500, 'unit': 'g'}},
 {'name': 'milk', 'qaunt_list': {'amount': 200, 'unit': 'ml'}},
 {'name': 'butter', 'qaunt_list': {'amount': 40, 'unit': 'g'}}]
```